# Bruteforce log visualization

Tags: logging, visualization

Hi could you recommend good tool to visual bruteforce attacks withing normal connection to ssh/MTA...?

I have seen for free only afterglow.

Thanks in advance,
Dawid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a static visualization, use **Gource** http://gource.io/ that can create a movie and show your bruteforce attack "log by log" based on timestamp of each event.

If you need a dynamic / interactive visualization, you can use the **Vis.js** "network map" that is a dynamic, browser based, visualization library (JavaScript).

I was looking for a JavaScript alternative to Gource for a long time. So i made a Node.js Dashboard that use Vis.js and FontAwesome. If can be helpful: https://github.com/theMiddleBlue/RealTimeVis.js

-theMiddle

Answer (score 3):

Try ccze?

```
$ ccze < /var/log/secure
```

Comment: To Visualize not to colorize :| Like afterglow, picviz, skyrails.

Comment: Try Zenmap or Maltego in that case